# Turn percentages to decimals in a column that contains both

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm cleaning a data frame and one of the columns contains percentage values, decimal values, and blank/NA values. I've read this data in from a CSV file and it's been read in as a character field:

| value |
| --- |
| 15% |
| 20.5% |
| NA |
| 0.17 |
| 0.356 |

I want to turn all the percentage values into decimals so that it becomes:

| value |
| --- |
| 0.15 |
| 0.205 |
| NA |
| 0.17 |
| 0.356 |

I've tried to use `case_when` and `grepl` to evaluate when the row contains a '%', to remove the character and then divide by 100 but I'm getting error.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(
    is.na(value) ~ NA,              # to keep the NAs
    grepl("%", value, fixed = TRUE) ~ as.numeric(gsub("%", "", value))/100,              # to fix the %s
    .default = value              # to keep the decimal values
    )
  )
```

The error I get is:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `value = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! Case 3 (`is.na(value) ~ NA`) must be a two-sided formula, not a
  character vector.
```

I don't have to use `case_when` so will accept answers that achieve the same goal but in a different way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `.default = value` is returning characters while the rest of your conditions return numeric values. Columns are atomic so they must be the same type. To fix your code you need to do:

```
.default = as.numeric(value)
```

**Explanation**

`is.na(value)` might not be doing anything. You see `NA`, but R just sees a string `"NA"` which is not the same. Try running `is.na("NA"); is.na(NA)` . Many routines that read CSVs will auto detect these string values and replace them with `NA`.  Just an FYI.

If your `NA` is a true `NA` then `.default` will return `"0.17" "0.356"`. Again you can see these are numbers but they are in fact characters to R. You cannot mix types in vectors and data frame columns. R has a hierarchy for coercing types that can be dangerous. So here instead of coercing it just throws an error.

---

Otherwise, here is an alternative:

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(value = ifelse(grepl("%", value), readr::parse_number(value) / 100, as.numeric(value)))
```

Note: both your solution and mine might throw a warning message like

> NAs introduced by coercion

This is because `as.numeric("NA")` will try to convert this value to a number and when it cannot it will coerce it to `NA`.

**Output**

```
  value
1 0.150
2 0.205
3    NA
4 0.170
5 0.356
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach in base R without an `mutate`/`ifelse` statement:

```
df$newvalue <- as.numeric(gsub("%", "", df$value))
df$newvalue[grepl("%", df$value)] <- df$newvalue[grepl("%", df$value)] / 100
```

Output

```
# value newvalue
#1   15%    0.150
#2 20.5%    0.205
#3  <NA>       NA
#4  0.17    0.170
#5 0.356    0.356
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "value
15%
20.5%
NA
0.17
0.356", h = TRUE)
```